# build numpy d-dim array from iterator of (d-1)-dim array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a use case, and I simplify it to following question:

```py
import numpy as np

def get_matrix(i): # get a matrix N * M
    return (
        (i, i + 1, i + 1.2),
        (i + 1, i / 2, i * 3.2),
        (i / 3, i * 2, i / 4),
        (i / 5, i * 2.1, i + 2.2),
    )

K = 10000
# build a n-d array K * N * M
arr = np.array(
    tuple(get_matrix(i) for i in range(K)), 
    np.float32,
)
```

However, when I want to get `K*N*M` numpy array, I need to create a temporary tuple with shape `K*N*M`. Only when numpy array has been built, the tuple can be garbage collected. Therefore above construction has extra space `O(K*N*M)`.

If I can create the numpy array from iterator `(get_matrix(i) for i in range(K))`, then every matrix `N*M` can be garbage collected, when it has been used. Therefore the extra space is `O(N*M)`.

I found there is a method [`numpy.fromiter()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html), but I don't know how to write the [dtype](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html), since there is a similar example in the [last](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html).

```py
import numpy as np

K = 10000
# build a n-d array K * N * M
arr = np.fromiter(
    (get_matrix(i) for i in range(K)), 
    dtype=np.float32, # there is error
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, so this is a new feature for `np.fromiter`. Just going by the example in the docs, the following worked:

```
K = 10000
N = 4
M = 3

# build a n-d array K * N * M
arr = np.fromiter(
    (get_matrix(i) for i in range(K)), 
    dtype=np.dtype((np.float32, (N, M))),
    count=K
)
```

Note, I used the `count` argument for good measure, but it works without it.